# Inward facing 360 degree photo

Tags: image, image-processing, graph, computer-vision, 360-degrees

Problem statement:

I want to grab a smartphone, take a series of photos (or a video) of an object, and convert it to a 360 degree photo.

Some Research:

If we look at [Facebook 360 Photos](https://facebook360.fb.com/360-photos/), this is exactly what I'm looking for, *except* that Facebook's solution is outward-facing 360 photos, and I'm looking for ***inward*** facing 360 photos.

This objective seems to be similar to [360 degree product photography](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=360+degree+product+photo&oq=360+de&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i57j0l3.1737j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Important difference: I do not want to use any special equipment other than a smartphone. Just like you can create a 360 degree outward facing photo without needing a tripod or a turntable.

I want to understand from the community:

1. Does a solution like this exist? What's the best we can do at the moment?
2. What kind of technological expertise would a person require to create something like this? Consider yourself an investor or a CEO who needs to get this built. Who do you hire? Who do you consult?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a fundamental difference between the two cases:

- "Outward": the translation of the camera is small. If the scene is far enough away, it can be ignored, and the camera motion can be approximated with a rotation about its focal point (there is almost no parallax between views). The mapping from one image to any other image is well approximated a homography, and the image set maps naturally to the inner surface of a sphere (or, aproximately, a cylinder, a cube, etc.). A scene far away will also appear to move slowly, therefore capture time is less of a factor when stitching images.
- "Inward": the translation is large and cannot be ignored. There is parallax, the scene objects may self-occlude or mutually occlude each other in some of the images, making "stitching" highly nontrivial - mapping of one image onto the other depends on the scene content, unlike the outward case. If the content of the scene moves, stitching becomes an even harder problem.

In both cases, however, one normally relies on bundle adjustment for the final refinement of the camera poses/positions. In the second case the 3D geometry of the scene may need to be reconstructed, depending on the application.

To your questions:

1. Of course a solution exists: have you seen "The Matrix" with its "bullet-time" effect? Doing a google search of "bullet time" shows several more or less successful attempts at reproduction - the easiest involves tying an iPhone on a string and swinging it around.
2. Someone with background and expertize in photogrammetry, 3D computer vision (roughly, they have read and internalized Hartley & Zisserman's book or equivalents), and nontrivial image processing - there is some art involved in stitching correctly once you have solved the photogrammetry, it's not "just graphcut it and then multiband-blend it"